# Array is undefined when trying to push into it

Tags: arrays, typescript, foreach, enums, undefined

I am trying to push into an array some values from a model.

`public model: WeekDays[];`

WeekDays is an enum of this type

```
export enum WeekDays {
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday,
}
```

So i have a save function which should do the following:

```
public save(){
        this.model.forEach(function (value){
            this.arr.push(WeekDays[value]);
        })
    }
```

I want to get each element of the model and add the value of the days.
For example, if i have Monday and Tuesday in model, when performing

```
console.log(WeekDays[value])
```

the output is

```
0
1
```

And these values i want to add in my array but i get the "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arr')" error.

The array is defined as

```
arr = Array(7);
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want. Does this help? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA6swGsAiBDAngZygbwFBQKgFkB7EAE3QBp9CAVMYDStGw2YckJlt+gCzAAnZtVoEAYkICWvcVADKKAC7C57BWApiAvgG5cANxRCoJoQEYoAXigBtALoHjp8wCYb9h7gBmJUwAUADbAylCGUNIgHIiomACUOPLSPgHKaAAOwCQ+McjoGHaGDjbWtgDk4BAARsBC5Yl47ATmFgB0GWAY-AFwsQVFDvEGzWZCQm4dXT2Gw-I6uAsAxmQYJCFtQSQA5gEARK0AXHtzKyBrG1u7raer68CbO-vux7fn94-X427DQA

Comment: It helped. I solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `=>` to declare your `forEach` callback.

Functions declared with `=>` capture the value of `this` from the scope they were created in. `function` does not. So `this` is not what you think it is. It's most likely the global object, not your class instance.

Try this instead:

```
this.model.forEach((value) => {
  this.arr.push(WeekDays[value]);
})
```

Comment: Thank you.. forget about "=>" .. it works